# I'm getting this Error: Project raised exception class EDatabaseError with message 'sql: Field ' not found'

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Well guys, I have a little problem in this part of filtering the table fields, for example doing a name search for such tableX.

Only I'm getting this error:

```
Project  raised exception class EDatabaseError with message 'sql: Field ' not found'.
```

Next:

I used a ListName method, it was going to do a search for the name of my Table clients in the DBGrid case.

```
procedure TfrmConsult.ListarClients;
var
  Text: String;
begin

  Text := 'SELECT * from clients WHERE id > 0';
  if edtName.Text <> '' then
    Text := Text + ' AND name LIKE ' + Quotedstr(edtName.Text + '%');
    Text := Text + ' ORDER BY name';
  sqlClients.SQL.Text := Texto;
  sqlClients.Open;
end;
```

I linked more than one table to search other fields within a table in TZQuery's SQL, so I put it like this:

```
SELECT c. *, cit.city, cit.uf
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN city cit
ON cit.id = c.id
// Since there are 2 tables linked in SQL, it doesn't know why the field was not found in the Table.
```

I ended up finding an error, I just don't know how to solve it,
that I'm still new to Delphi, and speaking English is bad, but I hope you understand .... more if you can give me a strength there to understand and resolve, most importantly, I didn't give up.

I use Delphi XE2, TZQuery and Zeos

Comment: Please [edit] your title to be written in English. This is an English language only site. While you're making that edit, please include the entire, complete error message (translated to English) in your post itself and the table definition (column name and datatype) from your clients table. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you added the error message, which is one of the three things I asked for - can you take care of the other two now?

Comment: Remove the space.

Answer (score 1):

In your request:

```
SELECT c. *, cit.city, cit.uf FROM....
```

try removing the space between c. and * like this

```
SELECT c.*, cit.city, cit.uf FROM....
```